# Wordpress offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, configuration-files

I got a question.

I was working on my website, which makes use of Wordpress.
Because I was working on it I activated the Maintenance plugin.

I tried to integrate a simple slider, but it wasn't working.
So I tried to use the debug mode or something....

First of all I added "define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);" on the bottom of my wp-config.php
After that didn't work I deleted that line and added:

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

I already deleted all of that off the wp-config.php file.
There is seriously nothing different on that.

But now I am seeing a white screen and no code is loaded.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you enable php logging or check your error logs?

Comment: did you check your server's error log?

Comment: I guess I didn't enable php logging since I don't even know how to do that.
And the error log should be in my 'wp-content' folder but there wasn't any log....

Comment: I figured that I could acces the log files via the control panel:

Dec 30, 2013 08:38 PM access_log // Dec 30, 2013 06:09 AM access_log.processed // Dec 30, 2013 02:36 PM error_log // Dec 30, 2013 06:09 AM xferlog_regular

Comment: And seriously I don't know what happened, but all of the sudden everything just worked. Maybe a server error or something. Thanks Rogier21 and Nur.